# How to check if a callback function passed as a parameter in Javascript has arguments or not?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, javascript-objects

I have to do this

```
doSomething
    .then(success)
    .catch(failure);
```

And success and failure are callback functions which will get their value at run time (I am trying to write a module).

So I have to know that the function failure which is sent as a callback should have a parameter.

Because the callback is supposed to be like

```
function(error) {
// An error happened
}
```

Is there anyway in JS to do this? Or any library that makes this kind of checking possible?

**EDIT**

Just to clarify. I want a user(not end user), who uses my module, to send in a function as a parameter which will become a callback and I want to check if the function sent, which will be called back, has enough parameters required. I understand it is up to one who uses it to take care of that. But why not try?

Comment: there is an `arguments` array exposed in every function, which you can use to find out if any arguments are set, is that what you want?

Comment: Why do you need to know that? The person providing the function takes responsibility for its behavior. If they don't want to define a parameter, it shouldn't affect your code.

Comment: More broadly, there are static type checkers for JS if you desire compile-time type safety, but that seems quite beyond the concern in this question.

Comment: ...some of your use of terminology is confusing. Sometimes it sounds like you want to verify callbacks that you receive from others, and other times it sounds like you want to know what parameters you should be defining on your own callbacks. You're getting answers from both perspectives.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With a promise callback (your `then` and `catch` handlers), they will only be passed a single argument when called, and will always be passed that argument. *(If the promise is obeying native semantics; jQuery's `Deferred` doesn't always.)*

In the general case:

Usually you don't care, because in JavaScript, you can call a function with either fewer or more arguments than it has formal parameters. That is, this is just fine:

```js
function foo(a) {
  console.log("a = " + a);
}
foo();        // Fewer arguments than params
foo(1, 2, 3); // More arguments than params
```

Another reason you don't care is that the function can use arguments even when it doesn't declare formal parameters for them, by using a rest parameter or the `arguments` pseudo-array (you'll see why this snippet logs `foo.length` and `bar.length` in a moment):

```js
function foo() {
  console.log("First argument: " + arguments[0]);
}
function bar(...rest) {
  console.log("First argument: " + rest[0]);
}
foo(1);                                    // First argument: 1
bar("a");                                  // First argument: a
console.log("foo.length = " + foo.length); // foo.length = 0
console.log("bar.length = " + bar.length); // bar.length = 0
```

So just define what your API will call the callbacks with, and do that, and it's up to the users of the API to ensure that they use what you call them with correctly.

On those occasions it matters, you can use the function's `length` property to know how many formal parameters it declares:

```js
function foo(a) {
  console.log("a = " + a);
}
console.log(foo.length); // 1
```

Note that that will tell you how many formal parameters are declared...

- ...not counting a rest parameter (`...identifier`)
- ...only up until the first parameter with a default value (even if there are ones without a default after it)

So for instance:

```js
function foo(a, b = false, c) { // b has a default value
  console.log("a = " + a);
}
console.log(foo.length); // 1, even though `c` has no default value,
                         // because `c` is after `b`
```

and

```js
function foo(a, ...rest) {
  console.log("a = " + a);
}
console.log(foo.length); // 1, because the rest parameter doesn't count
```

Comment: Great! I had no idea with the length.

Comment: Also `foo.length` could be `0` due to it being defined with no arguments list and still the function expects arguments via the `arguments` object. If that makes sense. English, grrr!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir: Drat, I meant to mention that -- will do now, thanks! (Yes, that makes sense in English. :-) )

Comment: What's going on here with English? Making me slightly ...glish.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder fan of you.  :)

Comment: @GeorgeBailey: Golly. :-)

Comment: you always make me fall in love with your answers and knowledge :P JS

Answer (score 2):

It's probably an anti pattern for the caller to enforce a certain number of arguments of a callback, but if you must you can check the `length` of the function:

```js
function test() {}

function test1(a) {}

function test2(a, b) {}

console.log(test.length, test1.length, test2.length)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to know whether the function which is sent as a callback should have a parameter

You need to read the documentation of the function that you are sending the callback to. It will mention how (when, how often, and with what arguments) the callback is called.

For your `failure` that means reading the docs for [`catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) (assuming `doSomething` is a native promise). It says that the callback will be called with one argument, the rejection reason, when the promise is rejected.

> Or any library that makes this kind of checking possible?

You can use a typechecker that will warn you or throw an error when the function you are passing does not have the expected number of parameters.